# Mono FastCgi Responds with 200 success, but Nginx http response is 404 not found

Tags: asp.net, linux, nginx, mono, fastcgi

I'm trying to port a C# asp.net project to Ubuntu using Mono/Nginx/Fastcgi, and on some API requests, I'm seeing Nginx return a 404 http response when I'm expecting a 200. The application works fine with IIS on Windows servers, so I would really appreciate some help debugging this inconsistent behavior.

I'm using: mono 4.5 nightly, nginx 1.9, fastcgi-mono-server4 with a Net4.5 project.

My code compiles fine using `xbuild 'mysolution'.sln`, and I run

`fastcgi-mono-server4 /applications=/:/var/www/html/{folder containing my /bin} /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /printlog=True /verbose=True &` 
to turn on my mono fastcgi server, and then my nginx server `service nginx restart`

but on runtime when frontend requests hit any of my APIs, including the following API

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
[Route("UserRoles")]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserRoles(string userId)
{
    var userRoles = _repo.GetUserRoles(userId);
    return Ok(userRoles);
}
```

it SOMETIMES returns a 404 error, as opposed to a 200 success.

Tracking my http request/responses through Charles shows nginx is sending a 404 not found response, so I thought the issue is with the API.

However, adding a custom MessageHandler with added logging shows the API is receiving the request, processing it, then returning a 200 successful response. Looks like its somewhere between the MessageHandler and the nginx server that the response message goes from a 200 to a 404 not found.

Since replaying the same API request within Charles returns a 200 response, it seems like there's some resource constraint issue somewhere within Mono during multiple requests.

I've tried turning on debugging within nginx and fastcgi to get more useful logging: `error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;` within nginx.conf and using `loglevels=All` when running Fastcgi

but have not seen anything useful.

nginx configs /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/RM.WebAPI;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    rewrite_log on;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true'; 
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';

                    return 204;
            }

            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_next_upstream http_404; #invalid_header http_500;
            fastcgi_keep_conn off;
            autoindex on;

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

my custom MessageHandler MonoMessageHandler.cs

```
public class MonoMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Returning response {0}:{3} for request {1}\n Content:{2}", response.Result.ToString(), request.RequestUri.ToString(), response.Result.Content.ToString(), response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        return response;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: After I added a custom exception handler, I started getting the following error in my MessageHandler

```
 System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo
 Response:System.Web.Http.Results.ExceptionResult
 Exception:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at RM.WebAPI.MonoPatchingDelegatingHandler.SendAsync     (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x40f18640 + 0x0019d> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x40f18600 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<>n__FabricatedMethod9 (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage , CancellationToken ) <0x40f185d0 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Http.HttpServer+<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext () <0x40efbbb0 + 0x0042f> in <filename unknown>:0
```